# i have an error message like this Class 'MY_Controller' not found

Tags: codeigniter-3

Controller  filename is Auth.php

```
class Auth extends MY_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    //load model
    $this->load->model('Auth_model', 'auth');
    $this->load->model('Mail', 'mail');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
}
```

**but the following error keep appearing:**

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error
>
> Message: Class 'MY_Controller' not found
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\application\controllers\Auth.php
>
> Line Number: 16
>
> Backtrace:
>
> File: C:\xampp\htdocs\codeigniter\index.php Line: 315 Function:
>   require_once

Comment: This question has been answered many times. Try searching SO with the phrase **[codeigniter] my_controller not found**

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a file like `application/core/MY_Controller.php`;

then post your core functions in it. (don't forget to create `__construct()` function

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller
{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
} 
//your other rest codes will be here
```

Comment: This won't help. The constructor is pointless in your example. A call to the parent constructor is only needed when the child class overrides the parent's `__construct()` method.